# Django Forms Nested If - Second Condition

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a django form that checks if a postcode is valid and if valid it will perform a check against postcodes that are permitted for delivery. I cant get the second condition working in the nested if structure (works fine independently). This is the code:

```
from django import forms
import requests

class PostCodeForm (forms.Form):
    pcode = forms.CharField()

    def clean_pcode(self):
        pcode = self.cleaned_data['pcode'].lower()
        permitted = {'gu15','GF34','FG34','BT25'}
        url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/validate'.format(pcode)
        r = requests.get(url)
        is_correct = r.json()['result']
        if not is_correct:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Your postcode is invalid. Please re-enter a valid entry.")
            if not pcode[:4] in (permitted):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Apologies, but does not currently deliver to you postcode.")
                return pcode
```

Comment: What does "I can't get it working? mean? What happens? What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: If I enter a valid postcode called RM10 8QB the second validation error is not returned (when it should)

Comment: You are raising an error, I don't think the return line is reachable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your indentation, so that the second if statment and return statement are outside of the first if statement.

```
def clean_pcode(self):
    pcode = self.cleaned_data['pcode'].lower()
    permitted = {'gu15','GF34','FG34','BT25'}
    url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/validate'.format(pcode)
    r = requests.get(url)
    is_correct = r.json()['result']
    if not is_correct:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your postcode is invalid. Please re-enter a valid entry.")
    if not pcode[:4] in (permitted):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Apologies, but does not currently deliver to you postcode.")
    return pcode
```

As an aside, you should change the slicing from `pcode[:4]` to `pcode[:-3]`. This means that your code will still work if you add 3-character post districts (e.g. GU1) to your `permitted` set.

Also, since you call `lower()`, you need to make sure all your entries in `permitted` are lowercase. Personally, I would use `upper()` for normalising postcodes.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it! The case was already sorted on my code but I completely agree around using [:-3]